# Make titles on help page consistent

Tags: feature-request, status-review, help-center

If you go to this page (https://stackoverflow.com/help), it shows multiple headings:

- "Asking"
- "Our model"
- "Reputation & Moderation"
- "Answering"
- "Badges"
- "Stack Overflow Jobs"

Since "Our model", "Reputation & Moderation", and "Stack Overflow Jobs" all have multiple words in them, and "Our model" is the only one with a word in it that isn't capitalized, I think this should be kept consistent.

This could be made consistent by capitalizing the m in "model" or by making Stack Overflow Jobs and Reputation & Moderation both lowercase which would look ugly.

[image]

Comment: I assume we're talking [Title Case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22title+case%22) here, right?

Comment: Yes, title case should be used for titles.

Comment: Perhaps it is to balance out the extra capitals in "Code of Conduct" and "Expected Behavior."

Comment: Unlikely, as those are using Title Case because they reference other pages, whose titles are such.

Comment: Yes-yes-yes...!, after 3.5 years in "status-review", we finally got that missing [Comma](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/385513/6). a bit of a useless Edit, I would think, @SpencerG... // Maybe more useful would be to edit out the Ref to "*Stack Overflow Jobs*", or can we still hope for Capitals on "*What is a fake **J**ob **L**isting?*"...? :wink:

Comment: A **one-character typo** in a page generated by the site software (not editable by the community) has been in review for **three and a half years**, and then today a staff member finally comes along to make a one-character edit (arguably not actually fixing a typo)... *to the Meta post itself*? Are we being mocked? Is there somewhere I can click to downvote Stack Exchange, Inc.?

Comment: @chivracq This is actually being worked on, but to get it to auto generate the ticket internally I had to make a minor edit to the question. Hence, the pointless edit.

Comment: @SpencerG, ah OK, LOL...! That explains *it* then indeed,,, Maybe worth adding a mini-Comment "next time", as such Threads get bumped, and there will always be sbd that will see it and will go and check the Revisions to find out what the Edit was, and that single added Comma felt very *strange*, maybe related to some "SLA-Technique", I thought... :idea: (Thanks for the Reply/Explanation btw...)